# TypeError from matplotlib Button instantiation

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I'm getting a mysterious error when I try to create a Matplotlib button.

I have a class which has a number of Matplotlib axes as instance attributes. I am instantiating the button with the following call:

`Button(self.energy_diagram, 'Show Attractors')`

And I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ocr.py", line 20, in <module>
    myNet.run_visualization(training_data, learning_data)
  File  "/home/daniel/Documents/coding/visuals.py",    line 93, in run_visualization
    self._plot_energy()
  File     "/home/daniel/Documents/coding/visuals.py", line 235, in _plot_energy
    Button(self.energy_diagram, 'Show Attractors')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/matplotlib/widgets.py",     line 191, in __init__
    transform=ax.transAxes)
TypeError: text() missing 1 required positional argument: 's'
```

Interestingly, the Button works if I add it to other axes within my figure, and the `self.energy_diagram` axis is the only one that is 3d, so I'm wondering if that has something to do with it.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your error message. It's surprising, but fairly clear. Your note about the problematic axes being the only 3d one is the key. Two minimal examples with and without the error:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.widgets as widgets

hf1,ha1 = plt.subplots()
ha1.plot([1,2,3],[4,5,6])
butt1 = widgets.Button(ha1,'button 1')     # <-- works great

hf2 = plt.figure()
ha2 = hf2.add_subplot(111,projection='3d')
ha2.plot([1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9])
butt2 = widgets.Button(ha2,'button 2')     # <-- error
```

First, a look at /usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/matplotlibwidgets.py, around line 191:

```
class Button(AxesWidget):
    def __init__(self, ax, label, image=None,
                 color='0.85', hovercolor='0.95'):
        AxesWidget.__init__(self, ax)

        if image is not None:
            ax.imshow(image)
        self.label = ax.text(0.5, 0.5, label,
                             verticalalignment='center',
                             horizontalalignment='center',
                             transform=ax.transAxes)   # <-- line 191
```

The button attempts to call the `text` method of the `Axes` it's being put into, and this call is producing the error. With the `help` of `ha1.text` (bound version of `matplotlib.pyplot.Axes.text`):

```
text(x, y, s, fontdict=None, withdash=False, **kwargs) method of matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot instance
    Add text to the axes.

    Add text in string `s` to axis at location `x`, `y`, data
    coordinates.
```

The same for `ha2.text` (bound version of `mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.Axes3D.text`):

```
text(x, y, z, s, zdir=None, **kwargs) method of matplotlib.axes._subplots.Axes3DSubplot instance
    Add text to the plot. kwargs will be passed on to Axes.text,
    except for the `zdir` keyword, which sets the direction to be
    used as the z direction.
```

Spot the difference: the latter function has to receive a `z` coordinate as well in order to place the text on the 3d axes. Makes sense. The `Button` widget is simply not designed to work with 3d axes.

Now, you could try hacking yourself around the problem, although the fact that `Button` is clearly lacking 3d axes support suggests that you will sooner or later shoot yourself in the foot. Anyway, you can actually get rid of the error by overwriting the `text` method of `ha2` with that of `ha1` with some adjustments to put `self` in the right place. Again, I'm not saying that this can't break anything anytime, *nor* that it's something horrible to do, but it's an option:

```
hf2 = plt.figure()
ha2 = hf2.add_subplot(111,projection='3d')
ha2.plot([1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9])
ha2.text = lambda x,y,s,self=ha2,**kwargs : plt.Axes.text(self,x,y,s,kwargs)
butt2 = widgets.Button(ha2,'button 2')     # <-- no error
```

For what it's worth, it now looks as bad as the 2d version:

[image: 2d version] [image: bad bad ugly 3d version]

This leads me to my final point. As far as I can tell, widgets automatically occupy the entire axes they're put into. And it seems reasonable to *not* put a widget (an inherently 2d object) into a 3d axes: how exactly do you want it to be positioned? The obvious solution would be to store each widget in its own axes, on top of/next to the other GUI components and figures. This way you can naturally use 2d axes for each widget. I believe this is the standard approach for doing this, which might explain why there's no explicit mention of 3d axes not being supported. Why would they be?

Comment: Wow, I forgot about this post for a while but thank you for this incredibly thorough answer!!! I just started working on my project again and this is enormously helpful.